# Can I use an Outlook Anywhere account?

Tags: email, ms-exchange

My company uses Outlook Anywhere with Exchange 2010. How can I set up an account on Ubuntu with Outlook Anywhere?

I'm not wanting to use pop or any other protocol, just Outlook Anywhere.

Comment: There's `OWA` which is a web interface. I use that when I'm outside the corporate firewall and need to access email.

Answer (score 0):

Evolution has microsoft exchange support you just need to know the OWA address to configure evolution. to install evolution open a terminal ctrl alt t then sudo apt-get install evolution.

Comment: Evolution comes with Ubuntu 10.10 by default, when I try to use the Server Type "Microsoft Exchange" I get an error message that says: **"The Exchange Server is not compatible with Exchange Connector. The server is running Exchange 5.5. Exchange Connector supports Microsoft Exchange 2000 and 2003 only."**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thunderbird supports Outlook Anywhere quite well.  You should not have any problems.

Comment: I don't believe thunderbird supports Outlook Anywhere at all. I've installed the latest version through their ppa and I don't see any support for it at all. If you could provide a link or anything if there is a plugin or something, that would be great

Comment: Well, I had an Outlook Anywhere account set up in Ubuntu 11.04. When I upgraded to 11.10, it imported my evolution account and all it's settings. It sends, reads, and synches email just fine, and I have  not had any problems.

Comment: See these settings: http://www.g2support.com/2010/05/thunderbird-and-exchanage-2010/

Comment: That link is bad

Comment: Add a slash to the end of the URL, for some reason its not taking the slash.

Comment: Here is the correct link  [http://www.g2support.com/2010/05/thunderbird-and-exchange-2010/](http://www.g2support.com/2010/05/thunderbird-and-exchange-2010/)      Thanks, but that link does not really have anything to do with Outlook Anywhere and it doesn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

The latest gnome spin of ubuntu comes with exchange web services support. Mail contacts and calendars. This is the only reliable way of achieving this without using imap or pop. 
Your organisation needs to hsve the web services exposed.